# What is "fref=uri" when viewing a Facebook profile page?

Tags: facebook-profile

When opening someone's Facebook profile page, I often see `fref=uri` at the end of their URL, e.g. mine is [https://facebook.com/namgivu?**fref=uri**](https://facebook.com/namgivu?fref=ufi)

Without such `fref` suffix, I can go to the same profile page.

What does `fref=uri` mean then?

Comment: uri I guess. Will update and thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to be a referrer for Facebook's analytics.

For example:

`fref=ts` on the end of the URL means that the page was linked from a "Top Search".  Basically the user was sent there from a search engine result.

`fref=nf` means that the user arrived from their news feed.

I'm thinking that `fref=uri` means that the user arrived from an external site.